# How do I compute the fundamental matrix from Kitti dataset?

Tags: python, computer-vision

I am working on the Kitti stereo dataset (http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/eval_stereo.php) and I want to compute the fundamental matrix, which was not given in the calib file. However, for a pair of stereo images, the following info are given:

```
S_xx: 1x2 size of image xx before rectification
K_xx: 3x3 calibration matrix of camera xx before rectification
D_xx: 1x5 distortion vector of camera xx before rectification
R_xx: 3x3 rotation matrix of camera xx (extrinsic)
T_xx: 3x1 translation vector of camera xx (extrinsic)
S_rect_xx: 1x2 size of image xx after rectification
R_rect_xx: 3x3 rectifying rotation to make image planes co-planar
P_rect_xx: 3x4 projection matrix after rectification
```

How do I compute the fundamental matrix from these?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the translation and rotation between the two cameras, you can use information from:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_matrix
to calculate the essential matrix, and then using the cameras intrinsic calibration matrices to calculate the fundamental matrix as described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_matrix_(computer_vision)